# Prompt is displaying at the end of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that i am displaying the a JQuery prompt message (with Yes/No buttons) to the user for getting his option. This prompt message is being displayed correctly,in middle of the page for Fire Fox, but when i try the same on IE, in that case it display the prompt message at the end of my page. I want to show the prompt in the middle of the page when i am running it on IE, just like it does for Fire Fox. Please help

Caller Method from my JSF method :

```
if(/*My conditions goes here*/)
{
    jConfirmyesno('Do you want to Save the selected Do Not Print criteria for selected Patient?','Prompt',aftetYesNoPopup);
}

function aftetYesNoPopup(val)
{
    alert("In parent methid after jquery: "+val);

    if(val)
    {
        alert("Setting yes value");
        //My remaining code in case when user press yes button

    }

}
```

And my  part of code in related JQuery is:

```
jConfirmyesno = function(message, title, callback) {
    //alert("recieved the call");
    $.alerts.confirmyesno(message, title, callback);
};
```

And part of switch block which handles the request from the above function is:

```
case 'confirmyesno':
    $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' +  $.alerts.yesButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.noButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>'); 
    $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                                         //alert("press yes button");
                                         $.alerts._hide();

                                         if( callback ) 
                                             callback(true);
                                     });
    $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                                             //alert("press no button");
                                             $.alerts._hide();

                                             if( callback ) 
                                                 callback(false);
                                         });
    $("#popup_ok").focus();
    break;
```

Comment: which version of IE are u using?
and can u please share your code...

Comment: I am using IE9 64 bit version

Comment: can we have a look at what you have tried???

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Most probably it's a CSS problem, not JavaScript. Try to create a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: Another problem is that whenever i try to call it through button click event than it display me the prompt. But when i try it through Enter key event than it always return me the yes value without displaying any alert....